# Handling repetetive data in Spark dataframes/datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am new to Spark and Scala and even after reading various documents I am still unable to find best way to solve an issue.

I have a fairly large data set (~TB) that could be loaded into a dataframe as follows:

1. 1 million rows
2. Columns are `time`, `data`, `Info1`, `Info2`.
3. Except `time` which is a float, all others are arrays of floats of size ~200K.
4. `Info1` and `Info2` are identical for all rows.
5. It appears that shared variables (such as broadcast variables) cannot be accessed by dataframes/data sets.
6. Rows can be case classes but they can't have static variables/companion objects in Spark.
7. Rows cannot be regular classes.
8. Only way out seems to have redundancy with `info1` and `info2` being same across all columns, but it seems terribly expensive in cases such as these.
9. Using `crossJoin` may have too much communication cost.

I would be grateful for any inputs in representing the data in Spark.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one of the simplest solutions wherein a new column with a constant is added:

```
val arr = Array(12.223F, 12.1F, 213.21F)
val df1 = df2.withColumn("info", lit(arr))
```